# html 5 input type for alphanumeric on mobile keyboard

Tags: html, text, input, alphanumeric

We have seen when input type "Text" selected on mobile keyboard it comes up with text, when input type "number" selected on mobile keyboard it comes up with numbers only. And when input type password fields are selected then it comes up with both alphabet and numbers. Is there any way to show both alphabet and numbers on keyboard when input field are not password, rather plain text??

[image: Like this]

Hope you got my query.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the `type=tel` it shows numbers with letters.

Comment: i understand how "tel" input works, but i wanted a bit smoother, i have edited the main posts, this keyboards were shown when pressed password field, is it possible like this for normal input also?

Comment: There is a plugin called jQKeyboard.  It should provide you with the UI you are looking to create.
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Responsive-Virtual-Keyboard-Plugin-With-jQuery-jQKeyboard.html

Comment: Thanks. Becoming hopeful, but if i try this on mobile , it opens up normal default keyboard and underneath this built keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Before html5.1 via css:

```
 input[type=number] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This should work too, using `type="number"`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="url">
```

> Try this input types it will show both number and text

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" inputmode="verbatim" />
```

The inputmode attribute tells the browser on devices with dynamic keyboards which keyboard to display."verbatim" is used for alphanumeric content.

Answer (score -4):

Please see [this](http://mobileinputtypes.com/) example for different kinds of keyboard inputs on mobile devices.

The keyboard that is closest to your wishes is probably the 'password' keyboard:

`<input type="password">`